# Python JSON - Remove 'value' key and its value if only 'key' presents

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON data. I want to remove the 'value' key if only 'key' presents.

I want to remove 'Job' and 'Mob No' and keep rest of them as it is.

Actual output:

```json
{
  "Name": "Nelson",
  "Country": "India",
  "Main": [
    {
      "Property": "House",
      "details": [
        {
          "key": "No",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "key": "Place",
          "value": "KAR"
        },
        {
          "key": "Job"
        },
        {
          "key": "Mob No"
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "Name": "Nelson",
  "Country": "India",
  "Main": [
    {
      "Property": "House",
      "details": [
        {
          "key": "No",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "key": "Place",
          "value": "KAR"
        }
      ]
    }
]
}
```

I tried using the below function:

```
def remove_empty_values(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in list(data.items()):
            if isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, dict):
                remove_empty_values(value)
            elif key == "attributes":
                for detail in value:
                    if isinstance(detail, dict) and "key" in detail and "value" in detail:
                        if "key" in detail and "value" in detail:
                            if not detail["value"]:
                                del detail["value"]
            elif key == "value" and not value:
                del data[key]
```

And calling above function by loading it in json.loads but the output is None.

I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: What have you tried on your own?

Comment: ```details``` refers to a list.  iterate through that list and check for the key values.

Comment: You criteria are unclear. Are you wanting to remove any dictionary with a value of either 'Job' or 'Mob no'? What if there are other values? Maybe you just want to remove all dictionaries that have only one key (regardless of value). The point is that you can arrive at that output in various ways but how you implement it depends on what the real rules are

Comment: Yes. I want to remove all dictionaries that have only one key regardless of value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a list comprehension to replace the 'details' list as follows:

```
import json # only needed for output presentation

d = {
  "Name": "Nelson",
  "Country": "India",
  "Main": [
    {
      "Property": "House",
      "details": [
        {
          "key": "No",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "key": "Place",
          "value": "KAR"
        },
        {
          "key": "Job"
        },
        {
          "key": "Mob No"
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
}

for m in d.get('Main', []):
    if 'details' in m:
        m['details'] = [_d for _d in m['details'] if len(_d) != 1]

print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "Name": "Nelson",
  "Country": "India",
  "Main": [
    {
      "Property": "House",
      "details": [
        {
          "key": "No",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "key": "Place",
          "value": "KAR"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:**

The check for existence of the 'details' key is just there to make the code more robust. It's not necessary for the data shown in the question.

Thus, if you have high confidence in the structure and content of the dictionary (JSON) then it's just:

```
for m in d['Main']:
    m['details'] = [_d for _d in m['details'] if len(_d) != 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

if the structure of the json file is fixed, you can do like this.

```py
import json

data = json.loads(json_str)
for i in len(data["Main"]):
    data["Main"][i]["details"] = [datum for datum in data["Main"][i]["details"] if datum["key"] not in keys]
output = json.dumps(data)
```